# Styling labels with amcharts

Tags: amcharts

Is it possible to style the Category axis labels as seen in the screenshot? Only basic text is allowed in the settings (no HTML) and using :before or :after selectors doesn't have any effect. Any ideas?

[image: Amcharts image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using AmCharts 3, you can set the `labelText` property of a AmGraph to a string containing tags like `[[value]]`, `[[description]]`, `[[percents]]`, `[[open]]`, `[[category]]` and HTML tags. For example, you could use something like:

```
labelText: "<b>[[value]] BILLION</b><br>[[category]]"
```

Answer (score 0):

To change color of a category, when config amcharts, you need to define some colors in "colors" array.
What else do you need in term of "style" ?